# Are off-topic posts to be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/679/72) as "not an answer", which is explained as follows.

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

My flag was declined, and the following explanation was given.

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I don't understand the explanation. This answer is not just technically inaccurate or altogether wrong. It is *not an answer* to my question. It is off topic not only there but even on the site, since it is not about politics. It could possibly be a comment, but as an answer it makes no sense whatsoever.

Could you explain this to me?

Comment: In my opinion, The explanation is simple:  the moderator evaluated your flag in error.  The answer posted on that question doesn't appear to attempt answer the question asked at all.

Answer (score 8):

Agreed, the "answer" is tangentially related commentary that doesn't even come close to an attempt to answer your question. I flagged it as well and upvoted your comment, it's a good enough explanation of why the "answer" doesn't really stand as an answer.

I can't (obviously) know why your flag was declined, but I must admit that I had to read both your question and the "answer" twice to be absolutely certain it's not an answer. I've added a link to this Meta discussion in my flag, I'm assuming that if it gets declined again, we'll get a full explanation about it here.

Comment: Thank you. The answer is now deleted. A new non-answer has been posted there since, and I've flagged it too. We'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 5):

I declined the flag, perhaps incorrectly, but  I did eventually reconsider and remove the post as a [broken window](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/). So a bit of background —

When responding to an answer flag, I am typically looking for *"exceptional"* situations like misuse of the feature, answers that should have been comments, spam, egregiously bad content, etc. A cursory reading seemed to indicate this was simply a *poor* answer — a situation preferably handled by down-voting the content so the best stuff can rise to the top. That's how the system is designed; moving on.

But upon reviewing subsequent flags (some with further explanation and then this meta post), I reconsidered the activity and motivation behind the post. Such un-cited claims are often used to advance an agenda or just to push your point of view. There's nothing inherently wrong with voicing a strongly-held opinion (especially in a political forum), but we're trying to do something a bit different here. The best way to curtail this kind of content is by vigilantly enforcing what we consider so-called *constructive* questions (and answers) in the context of [***this* type of Q&A**](https://superuser.com/about).

> **Broken Windows**
>   It’s pretty clear now that the broken windows theory applies to community sites as well. The theory is that minor forms of bad behavior encourage worse ones: that a neighborhood with lots of graffiti and broken windows becomes one where robberies occur.

We really *are* trying to do something a bit different with Politics SE.  As such, I am  going to be starting a clean-up effort for culling the content that doesn't quite fit in the Stack Exchange model — stay tuned — so this seemed as good a place as any to start.

Thanks for the discussion.